# Is there a way to make clickables nodes using flowcharty.js?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular and I want to have a dynamically generated flowcharts,currently using flowcharty.js but problem is couldnt make nodes clickable .Is there any way to have clickable components using flowcharty  or any other javascript librabies which can draw dynamic flowcharts.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then improve your question accordingly

Comment: I have tried using flowcharty.js and was able to generate dynamic flow charts  but I need click option on flow chart components .